# C++ How to correctly cap FPS (Using GLFW)

Tags: c++, sleep, glfw, frame-rate

So I have been trying to limit my fps to 60:

```
//Those are members inside the Display class
double tracker = glfwGetTime();
const float frameCap = 1 / 60.0f;

void Display::present() {
    glfwSwapBuffers( _window );

    //Getting the time between each call
    double now = glfwGetTime( );
    double frameTime=now - tracker;
    tracker=now;
    
    //delaying if required
    if ( frameTime < frameCap )
        delay( frameCap - frameTime );
}
```

```
void game() {
//Creating window and opengl context
.....

//Disabling "vsync" so i can cap fps by my own
glfwSwapInterval(0);

 while(running) {
   //Rendering and updating
   .........   

   //Swap buffers and delay if required
   display.present();
 }
}
```

My delay/sleep function

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

void delay( uint32_t ms )
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    Sleep( ms );
#else
    usleep( ms * 1000 );
#endif
}
```

Basically the idea to cap the framerate in each Display::present() call.

It looks like that nothing is being capped at all in fact the fps is 4000+

Comment: You probably wouldn't want to "sleep" just for framerate anyway. This could cause you to miss input messages, or run slower than 60fps if your program is running slow. It might help to read [Fix Your Timestep](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/) for more information. The blog post is directed toward game development, but the same principles apply here the update/draw loop

Comment: Changing the answer in a way that makes already given answers partially wrong (or completely wrong), because you removed a problem that is targeted in the answer, is a really bad habit and must not be done. This is a Q&A platform and not a forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first call of `present` your `double frameTime=glfwGetTime( ) - tracker;`, sets `frameTime` to the difference between the current time (`glfwGetTime()` and the inital value of `tracker` you set with `glfwGetTime()`.

In the next line, you set `tracker=frameTime;` (`frameTime` is not the time but the difference here.)

For the next call of `present`, the value `tracker` is really small (as it is the difference and not the time), as of that your `double frameTime=glfwGetTime( ) - tracker;` becomes really large (larger than `frameCap`), so there the sleep won't happen.

For the next call of `present` the condition of `( frameTime < frameCap )` might be true again, but for the flow up it definitely won't be anymore again.

So for at least every second invocation of `present` the `delay` won't be called.

Besides that `glfwGetTime` returns seconds, `frameCap` also represents how many seconds a frame should last, but your `void delay( uint32_t ms )` expects milliseconds.